# Wild bootstrap can't be computed for SVAR model in R

Tags: r, bootstrap, vector-autoregression

I'm trying to plot an impulse response function for a SVAR model. In order to build confidence intervals I have to perform a bootstrap.

When I try to run a code with a help of a `wild.boot()` function from `svars` package

`boot <- wild.boot(structural.form, design = "recursive", distr = "rademacher", nboot = 1000, n.ahead = 36)` 
I get a message: *Error in A %*% Z : non-conformable arguments.

In my code `structural.form` is a svars model of 7 variables.
Estimated B matrix looks like this:

`[,1]          [,2]          [,3]          [,4]
adj_vol            5.213335e-02 -1.280324e-02    -0.0208028  1.427806e-02
adj_net_withd      2.122378e+04  7.482284e+04 -9072.9630827  1.973791e+03
adj_consum_plants  9.282985e+00  1.159126e+01     8.8891498  1.324618e+00
adj_gas_prod      -3.680830e+02 -2.318584e+03  5637.2075093  2.140145e+04
adj_renew         -3.075617e+03 -4.088800e+02  -528.5607959 -3.731591e+02
adj_coal_prod     -3.077430e+01  1.083428e+02  -900.4659953  9.733483e+02
adj_coal_stocks    1.481274e+00  1.363435e+00    -0.2179028 -4.313830e-01
                           [,5]          [,6]          [,7]
adj_vol            1.404583e-02 -9.585176e-03  2.110899e-02
adj_net_withd      1.457838e+04  8.629343e+03 -5.734609e+03
adj_consum_plants  8.714831e+00  7.717166e+00  4.703154e-01
adj_gas_prod       1.858331e+03  2.935180e+03  3.627462e+03
adj_renew          2.435884e+03  5.749629e+02  1.029050e+03
adj_coal_prod     -5.909348e+02  1.002620e+03 -2.198212e+02
adj_coal_stocks   -1.012386e+00  7.473476e-01  1.694276e+00`

Can you suggest what can be wrong?

P.S. I'm very new in coding and on this site. Don't really know how to format a question on this site using very fancy features.

Comment: **Upd.** I've removed one regressor and changed one regressor's type from exogenous to endogenous in a VAR model (which is a prerequisite for SVAR in my case) and the issue has been resolved.